# ReactJS bind a component method the correct way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use `.bind()` when using a method in my component.
The reason is simple: In a loop I am returing Components and extend them with a property which is calling a method. But for every loop-item this I want to extend the `this` Object with some information (like a key).

Example:

**Items.jsx**

```
Items = React.createClass({
  eventMethod() {
    console.log('this event was triggered by key:', this.key);
  },
  items() {
    let items = [];
    let properties = {};
    _.each(this.props.items, (itemData, key)=>{
      properties.eventMethodInItem = this.eventMethod.bind(_.extend(this, {
        key
      }));
      let {...props} = properties;
      let item = <Item {...props} key={key} />;
      items.push(item);
    });
    return items;
  },
  render() {
    return(<div>{this.items()}</div>);
  }
});
```

**Item.jsx**

```
Item = React.createClass(...);
```

In this case (and its working) when the Item Component is triggering the prop "eventMethodInItem" my method "eventMethod" will be called and `this.key` has the correct value!

So - whats now the question ? Its working perfect, right ?

**Yes.**

But ReactJS does not want me to do this. This is what ReactJS is telling me as a console log.

***Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See Items***

Maybe you think its a "bad" way to add children to the component like I am doing it but in my special case I need to do this in this way - so I need to bind new information to a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to pretend that I understand what you are trying to do here, but maybe I can help clear it up anyway.

React takes all of the top level methods found on each component and automagically binds them to the context of the component.

This prevents other methods from overriding the context of `this` and as a result, if you try to rebind the method, React says "Hey don't bother. I already got it" — which is the warning you are seeing.

Assuming that you *really* want do this (each time you are mutating the outer `properties` object by overriding the `eventMethodInItem` property).

```
properties.eventMethodInItem = this.eventMethod.bind(_.extend(this, {
  key
}));
```

Then I can't see any reason that the `eventMethod` has to live on the component, rather than just in the scope of the `items` function.

```
items() {
  const eventMethod = function() {
    console.log('this event was triggered by key:', this.key);
  }
  // ...
  _.each(this.props.items, (itemData, key)=>{
    properties.eventMethodInItem = eventMethod.bind(_.extend(this, {
      key
    }));
    // ...
  });
},
```

That way you don't have to fight React to get your program to work.

Comment: You're right: In my case I don't have to use a  component method. Thanks for this great idea. I did not think about that obvious solution!

Comment: Just for fun: What about the fact when I have to use a Component Method but also want to extend the binded Object ?

Answer (score 2):

React is already autobinding `this` when using `React.createClass` http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation

Change your binding to

`properties.eventMethodInItem = this.eventMethod.bind(null,key);`

and your `eventMethod` to

```
eventMethod(key) {
    console.log('this event was triggered by key:', key);
}
```

I also suggest using `_.map` instead of `_.each`

```
items() {
  return _.map(this.props.items, (itemData, key) => {
    return <Item
          handleEventMethod={this.eventMethod.bind(null,key)}
          key={key} />;
  });
},
```

Comment: Binding the context to `null` is going to have the same effect and I think the asker wants to know why React doesn't want you to call `.bind` on component methods.

Answer (score 1):

Good pattern 
https://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes

Before :

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this. _handleClick = this. _handleClick.bind(this);
  this. _handleFoo = this. _handleFoo.bind(this);
 }
 // ...
}
```

After :

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
 _bind(...methods) {
  methods.forEach( (method) => this[method] = this[method].bind(this) );
 }
}

class ExampleComponent extends BaseComponent {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this._bind('_handleClick', '_handleFoo');
 }
 // ...
}
```

another good hacks for this topic http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html